# using javascript to display an image

Tags: javascript, css

I have an image as follow:
`<img id="imgId" src="img/cart.png" style="display: none"/>`
When a button is clicked, it calls a JavaScript function to display the image

```
document.getElementById("imgId").style.display = "inline"
```

The image is displayed well but it does not show up when I go back from another page.
What I want is after displaying the image, it will be still there even I go to another page and back.
Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: What do you have as a back-end to serve the pages? A little more information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by saving the image "state" in the URL-hash of the page. (The thing after # ).

When displaying the image, do it like this:

```
document.getElementById("imgId").style.display = "inline";
window.location.hash = "imgIdShown";
```

And on pageload you run this little piece of code.

```
if (window.location.hash == "imgIdShown")
{
    document.getElementById("imgId").style.display = "inline";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your state in a session if it's possible.